# Weakly dominance in Zero Sum game

Tags: game-theory

With the following game matrix in Zero sum games:

```
  a  b     
A -1  2
```

As b dominates over a - does this still prove there is Nash Equilibrium using minimax theorem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to usual interpretation, Column minimizes so actually $a$ *dominates* $b$. Regardless, the minimax outcome for this game (following the usual interpretation) is $(A,a)$.

Comment: so using minimax theorem can i say that (A,a) and (A,b) is the NE

Comment: Only $(A,a)$. 1 must play maximin and 2 must play minimax (which rules out your second answer).